# Storing GTFS realtime data in sql server using dot net core and c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, gtfs

I am working on a application which requires storing GTFS realtime data into sql server and querying it in every 30 sec for multiple agency.
Problem is, how to store and query data using c# in 30 sec because data will be coming from multiple agency and it could be large.

Could you please suggest the best solution for this issue

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: What's an "Agency". Is the "Agency" both selecting and inserting? What is "Large" here? I'm not sure I understand the concern. You run a SELECT statement every 30 seconds? Is it slow? Do you anticipate it being slow? Are you planning on optimizing the table for this SELECT through indexing or other means? I feel like there might be a lot of putting the cart before the horse here.

Comment: @JNevill I mentioned GTFS realtime data, GTFS realtime is a transit feed which is provided by multiple Agencies in form of json, xml, protobuf which includes information like vehicle positions, trip updates, alerts etc. I need to get this data from url parse it and load it to database but very quickly

Comment: Ah! Ok. I haven't worked with GTFS data before. Looks much nicer than EDI214 used in distribution.